# Custom AST in JavaCC?

Tags: abstract-syntax-tree, javacc

I've recently begun designing my first programming language, and being already fluent in java, I've started to build the AST API for my language in java. I plan on compiling to java byte-code, and that is functional and working in the current part of the AST that I've implemented. I've tried a couple different methods of parsing (that all failed) before stumbling upon parser-generators, in particular, JavaCC. I've done some basic research into JavaCC and EBNF, and was wondering if JavaCC could support a fully custom AST API (including constructor arguments and the like) while parsing my language. I wanted to ask this here before doing an deep research and watching/reading tutorials on JavaCC. From what I've seen, JavaCC can support AST's, but I'm not sure what the constraints are. Moreover, I know JavaCC has its own AST API, but I'd like to stick to the one I've developed already, as it is working and matches my language well.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Absolutely.  For example you can write nonterminals like this

```
CommandNode whileCommand() : {
    ExpressionNode e ;
    CommandNode doPart ;
} {
    <WHILE> e = expression() <DO>
    doPart = sequence() <ENDWHILE>
    { return new WhileCommand( e, doPart ) ; }
}
```

The builder pattern can be useful to isolate the parser from some of the details of the AST.

Comment: Awesome! Thanks. What about lookahead stuff? Like say I've arrived at an annotation node, but the annotation node is a parameter of the next field/method node, is that possible?

Comment: I'm not sure I understand the new question you raise.  I'll try to answer it anyway: Semantic actions aren't executed during lookahead, so you can use lookahead all you want without any interaction with your tree building. If that doesn't answer it, could you you post it as a new question with an example?

Comment: I suppose a better question would be "are there global variables," as what I want can be accomplished with that. So, does JavaCC support global variables.

Comment: Sure.  The parser class generated by JavaCC is just an everyday sort of Java class.  JavaCC just generates some of the methods for you (the parsing methods), but beyond that you can write the class any way you want. Thus you can declare fields in the parser class and these will be global variables with respect to the parsing methods. You can also put state (i.e. fields) into your builder object if you use the builder pattern.  Then the only field the parser needs is a reference to the builder object.

Comment: That's awesome. I didn't realize that JavaCC worked that way. I'll definitely look into it more, thanks for your help.